# Debian не видит монитор после переподключения кабеля

Tags: debian, monitor

Портативный монитор ASUS MB16AMT подключается к HTPC ASUS N50-E1 (через display port или hdmi). При включении компьютера изображение выводится, но если отключить и подключить снова кабель, то монитор не получит сигнал. В Windows11 такой проблемы нет. Можно ли как-то это решить в Debian? Делал `apt install amdgpu-install` - не помогло.